# Divergence of an Expression Involving the Gamma Function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, gamma-function

I want to show that
$$
\lim_{Re(t) \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(1+2t)\Gamma(-t)}{\Gamma(1+t)} (-z)^t
$$
diverges if $|z| > \frac14$.
I recognized that the expression involving the Gamma function is just the Beta function, $B(2t+1,-t)$, but I don't know much about the Beta function. Are there some properties of the Gamma function that I can use to prove this divergence? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments can be simplified using the Gamma duplication identity
$$
\Gamma(2s+1) = \frac{\Gamma(s+1)\Gamma(s+1/2)2^{2s}}{\sqrt{\pi}},
$$
and the Gamma reflection identity
$$
\Gamma(s+1)\Gamma(-s) = -\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}.
$$
So your expression is equivalent to
$$
-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sin(\pi s)}\frac{\Gamma(s+1/2)}{\Gamma(s+1)}(-4z)^s
$$

The first term in the product has a magnitude in the interval  $[\sqrt{\pi}\mathrm{sech}(\mathrm{Im}[s]), \sqrt{\pi}|\mathrm{csch}(\mathrm{Im}[s])|]$ (finite for all $\mathrm{Im}[s]\ne 0$) while the second term can be fairly easily shown from Stirling's approximation to scale as $s^{-1/2}$. So the limit diverges if $|z| > 1/4$ or $\mathrm{Im}[s] = 0$.

Comment: Wow! This is amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that some restriction has to be put on $s$ for this limit to make sense: for example, if $s\to\infty$ through positive real numbers, then the $\Gamma(-s)$ term has a pole at every integer, making the limit undefined.

As long as one is willing to restrict, say, the argument of $s$ to an interval like $[\varepsilon,\pi-\varepsilon]$, then this problem goes away and one can use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling%27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function) to asymptotically evaluate each term.

Comment: Say I restrict the argument to an interval, are you suggesting rewriting the expression involving the gamma functions using Stirling's formula and see if I can cancel out some part of it hopefully?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right!

Comment: I will try that, thanks!